# Run npm install script through php

Tags: php, bash, shell

I would like to run `npm install` within a folder to install some node modules, etc.

How do you do this in a PHP script?
I've tried a bunch of stuff and it's clear that I'm unclear on the actual issue ;)

I've tried the following:

`shell_exec("npm install");` (Fails)

`exec("npm install")` (fails with 127 error, meaning it can't find the script to run I think)

Any ideas?

Comment: Welp I had to actually install node on my vagrant machine, so now the exec command runs.  However, I still get a write-permissions issue when npm tries to create things. `Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/.npm'`  Is this something anyone is familiar with?

Answer (score 6):

There were 2 issues to deal with:

1. Install Node on my vagrant box.
2. Ensure correct permissions for the user which PHP runs it's exec() command with.

With the help of a colleague I was able to figure out the correct permissions to set.  I called `exec("whoami")` to see that PHP was using the `apache` user, and then SSH'd into vagrant and did the following:

```
cd /var
sudo chown apache:apache www
```

Then I was able to ensure my user was granted permissions by running

```
ls -l
```

An excerpt from the results is below.  You can see that the `www` folder has permissions set for `apache`

```
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root   root   4096 Nov 30  2015 spool
drwxrwxrwt.  4 root   root   4096 Oct 27 15:48 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  5 apache apache 4096 Jul 18 11:24 www
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root   root   4096 Sep 23  2011 yp
```

Here is what I am now able to successfully run via PHP:

`exec("HOME='".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."' && cd ./../tmp && npm install", $output, $status);`

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try with npm's whole path.
It can be found on Unix systems by running

```
which npm
```

in a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure `npm` is added to your system path. You can do this on windows by openening

**This pc** -> **system properties** -> **advanced system settings** -> **go to the tab advanced settings** -> **Enviroment variables** and then edit the `PATH`

My installation is found under `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` so I added that. Then restart the php application (make sure the process/IDE is reopened after you changed your PATH) and that should do the trick

Comment: If npm was not on the system path, wouldn't I have problems using it in the CLI?